# Disable /rest URL in ColdFusion10

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Our problem with ColdFusion 10 is that there is the `/rest/` URL binded. In our application we have a rest service ourselves. Since ColdFusion 10 it will not work because the URL is already defined and our requests won't get through. Is there any way to disable `/rest/` completely? Or do we have to rename our service?

I also tried to edit the axis2.xml file

```
<parameter name="disableREST" locked="true">true</parameter>
<parameter name="restPath">restdisabled</parameter>
```

But that won't effect anything on the server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I have not tried this and do not have a ColdFusion 10 installation nearby to verify*

There is a servlet mapping defined in the `web.xml` file that defines how to handle `/rest/` requests for ColdFusion. So you should be able to rename that URI to something else for your implementation. The `web.xml` file is located under the `wwwroot\WEB-INF` directory on your ColdFusion server.

I found some reference to this here - [Getting started with RESTful web services in ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html) (under the **Accessing a REST Service through HTTP** section)

That documentation also mentioned updating the `uriworkermap.properties` file. Here is an excerpt from that page:

> `rest` in the URL specifies that the request is for a REST service. ColdFusion has a servlet mapping for the same and would direct the request to the servlet that handles REST service. If there is a directory in the server webroot with the same name, you must update the servlet mapping in `web.xml` file inside `wwwroot\WEB-INF` directory. Also, you must update the same mapping in the `uriworkermap.properties` file located under the `config\wsconfig\1` of the server directory.

You will need to restart the ColdFusion service after making any changes to these files.

While this will not *disable* the functionality in ColdFusion it will allow your services to respond under the `/rest/` URI because ColdFusion will be listening under a different one that you define.